# ogr2ogr PostgreSQL installation without PostgreSQL driver (Windows). Why and how to change path to OSGeo installation

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, powershell

I'm trying to import a shapefile into my PostGIS database with `ogr2ogr` on Windows.

Running the command `ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=database host=localhost user=postgres port=5432" filename.shp` results the `unable to find driver PostgreSQL`

Listing the available drivers indeed shows that PostgreSQL is missing

```
format_name: output file format name, possible values are:
     -f "AmigoCloud"
     -f "Carto"
     -f "CSV"
     -f "DGN"
     -f "DXF"
     -f "Elasticsearch"
     -f "ESRI Shapefile"
     -f "FlatGeobuf"
     -f "Geoconcept"
     -f "GeoJSON"
     -f "GeoJSONSeq"
     -f "GeoRSS"
     -f "GML"
     -f "GPSBabel"
     -f "GPX"
     -f "JML"
     -f "KML"
     -f "MapInfo File"
     -f "MapML"
     -f "Memory"
     -f "MSSQLSpatial"
     -f "NGW"
     -f "ODS"
     -f "OGR_GMT"
     -f "OpenFileGDB"
     -f "PCIDSK"
     -f "PDF"
     -f "PDS4"
     -f "PGDUMP"
     -f "S57"
     -f "Selafin"
     -f "VDV"
     -f "VICAR"
     -f "WAsP"
     -f "XLSX"
```

This was a surprise, as I used the [OSGeo4W network installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). Apparently I already had a version of ogr2ogr.

Which is true according to result of this command in powershell `(get-command ogr2ogr).Path`:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\ogr2ogr.exe`

I want to point the environmental variable for ogr2ogr to path of OSGeo installation, but it is not listed in the list of environmental variables. Now I got stuck.

I have two questions, one practical and one more theoretical.

1. How can a change the path of the `ogr2ogr` command to the OSGeo installation
2. Why does is the PostgreSQL implementation of ogr2ogr missing its own PostgreSQL driver?

Comment: You are supposed to set the environment for OSGeo4W by running the "OSGeo4W.bat" file that is in the OSGeo4W installation directory. The Windows shortcuts, if installed, will run it for you.

Comment: You can also specify the full path to the ogr2ogr you want to use `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f PostgreSQL PG ...`